# giving ftp user a random password

Tags: php, ssh, exec

So I'm trying to create a new ftp user and directory and give him only permissions for that directory. But the problem is when setting a password for created user. It creates user but i get this when i try to set a password for him

> Creating home directory `/home/kwgazl69' ... Copying files from`/etc/skel' ... Enter new UNIX password: passwd: user 'test123' does not exist

What am i doing wrong ? Here is the code

```
$src = $request->path;
$dest = "/home/$randomNum/serverFiles";

echo $ssh->exec("adduser --force-badname $randomNum");
echo $ssh->exec("passwd test123");

echo $ssh->exec("cp -r $src $dest");
echo $ssh->exec("usermod -d $dest $randomNum");

echo $ssh->exec("cd $dest && ./samp03svr");

$ssh->disconnect();
```

> Adding user `ln2i78yt' ... Adding new group`ln2i78yt' (1010) ... Adding new user `ln2i78yt' (1010) with group`ln2i78yt' ... Creating home directory `/home/ln2i78yt' ... Copying files from`/etc/skel' ... Enter new UNIX password: passwd: unrecognized option '--stdin' Usage: passwd [options] [LOGIN] Options: -a, --all report password status on all accounts -d, --delete delete the password for the named account -e, --expire force expire the password for the named account -h, --help display this help message and exit -k, --keep-tokens change password only if expired -i, --inactive INACTIVE set password inactive after expiration to INACTIVE -l, --lock lock the password of the named account -n, --mindays MIN_DAYS set minimum number of days before password change to MIN_DAYS -q, --quiet quiet mode -r, --repository REPOSITORY change password in REPOSITORY repository -R, --root CHROOT_DIR directory to chroot into -S, --status report password status on the named account -u, --unlock unlock the password of the named account -w, --warndays WARN_DAYS set expiration warning days to WARN_DAYS -x, --maxdays MAX_DAYS set maximum number of days before password change to MAX_DAYS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`passwd` expects 1st parameter to be username, and after that it asks for password twice. You can try to use another command called `chpasswd`. It expects username and password separated by colon.

```
$src = $request->path;
$dest = "/home/$randomNum/serverFiles";

echo $ssh->exec("adduser --force-badname $randomNum");
echo $ssh->exec("echo \"$randomNum:test123\" | chpasswd");

echo $ssh->exec("cp -r $src $dest");
echo $ssh->exec("usermod -d $dest $randomNum");

echo $ssh->exec("cd $dest && ./samp03svr");

$ssh->disconnect();
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but how can i only give him permissions to acces his directory and serverfiles now a new user can access even root

Comment: You need to set file and directory permissions, so the user can't view certain directories. Check out this link: https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions

Answer (score 0):

You're actually trying to change the password for user 'test123', rather than set the password to 'test123'.

You need to pass the password into stdin, so do:

```
echo $ssh->exec('echo -e "test123\ntest123" | passwd ' . $randomNum);
```

Comment: I dont really get that. If the code is in php how can i echo inside the function ?

Comment: edited my answer - I meant a bash 'echo', not a PHP one.

Comment: i still can't get it to work i edited my question please check the log

Comment: Ah ok, you don't have a newer version of passwd. I'll update answer